# There is no difference in the network latency of clustar batch group and spread batch group

Tags: amazon-web-services

I made two ec2 instances at clustar batch group and also made two ec2 instances at spread batch group.
I do ping test between two ec2 instances at same batch group.
I expected the result of clustar batch group is better.
But, the result show dosent show difference.
The result of clustar batch group is 0.159ms, another result of spread batch group is 0.163ms.
Why the results show no difference?

Comment: It would probably be more meanful to measure throughout between the machines, and latency under strain.

Comment: Are you talking about **cluster** and spread **placement groups**?